# activar usuarios mediante código

Tags: php, wordpress

tengo este código en wordpress, que permite registrar un usuario, y la linea wp_mail le envía la clave generada aleatoriamente. y lo hace correctamente. Pero deseo que el usuario pulse un link para activar la cuenta, pero no encuentro la forma, ya que al intentar acceder al sitio con su correo y la clave generada, no ingresa al sitio web.

Quisiera saber si existe forma de activar la cuenta, o como generar manualmente el link al que deben pulsar para enviar la activación.

```
<?php if (isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {
   global $reg_errors;
  $reg_errors = new WP_Error;

  $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
  $user = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
  $ciudad = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ciudades']);

  if ( empty( $user ) ) {
    $reg_errors->add("empty-user", "El campo nombre es obligatorio");
  }
  if ( empty( $email ) ) {
    $reg_errors->add("empty-email", "El campo e-mail es obligatorio");
  }

  if ( !is_email( $email ) ) {
    $reg_errors->add( "invalid-email", "El e-mail no tiene un formato válido" );
  }

  if ( is_wp_error( $reg_errors ) ) {
    if (count($reg_errors->get_error_messages()) > 0) {
      foreach ( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() as $error ) {
        echo $error . "<br />";
      }
    }
  }

  if (count($reg_errors->get_error_messages()) == 0) {
    $password = wp_generate_password();

    $userdata = array(
    'user_login' => $user,
    'user_email' => $email,
    'user_pass' => $password
    );

    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );

    if ( !function_exists( 'xprofile_set_field_data' ) ) { 
    require_once '/bp-xprofile/bp-xprofile-functions.php'; 
  }

  $field = 10;

    wp_mail("micorreo@gmail.com", "Ejemplo de la función mail en WP", "Este es un ejemplo del contenido de del mensaje de la funcion wp_mail() de WordPress ".$password);

  $is_required = false; 

  $result = xprofile_set_field_data(10, $user_id, $ciudad, $is_required); 

}   
}
?>
```

de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontré la solución por propia cuenta, y espero les funcione, resulta que en la tabla wp_users existe un campo llamado status_user el cual contiene valores (0 - activo, 2 - inactivo o pendiente), y sólo cambie este valor después del registro y funcionó, Existe una función para hacer esto y es:

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
  update_user_status( $user_id, '', 0 );

la función la encontré [aquí](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_status/)

y la sintaxis general es

```
update_user_status( int $id, string $pref, int $value, null $deprecated = null )
```

espero les sirva de algo mi respuesta. saludos